# Java - Creating appointement in Exchange 2010 worked fine but not for 2016

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have to maintain a Java program which create appointements in Outlook for doctors.
It was working fine when we used Exchange 2010 but we had to upgrade to Exchange 2016.

Now, this programs fails 100% of the time with the error :

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exception.ServiceResponseException: Le dossier spécifié est introuvable dans la banque d'informations
```

I think the English message must be :

```
The specified object was not found in the store.
```

It still works on Exchange 2010 mail boxes.
I tried to migrate the admin account used for the credentials to Exchange 2016 but to no avail.

Here is the code I use (I removed some parts to make it easier to read) :

```
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.*;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.enumeration.* ;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.* ;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.misc.UserConfiguration;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.*;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.search.*;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.*;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.schema.*;
```

```
String ews = "https://owa.XXX.fr/ews/exchange.asmx" ; // URL Exchange Web Services 
ExchangeVersion exver = ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2; // This is a backward compatibility

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(exver);
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password,domain);
service.setCredentials(credentials);

try 
{       
    service.setUrl(new URI(ews));   
}
catch (URISyntaxException e1) 
{       
    e1.printStackTrace(); System.out.println("Erreur de connexion à exchange " );   
}

/*connexion à la boite mail du médecin*/
Mailbox mb = new Mailbox();
mb.setAddress("XXX@XXX.fr");

Appointment appointment = new  Appointment(service);
appointment.setSubject(nature + " : " + commentaire  );
appointment.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText(body));

FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, mb);
appointment.save(folderId);
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Edit : here is the full error stack :

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exception.ServiceResponseException: Le dossier spécifié est introuvable dans la banque d'informations.atm icrosoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.response.ServiceResponse.internalThrowIfNecessary(ServiceResponse.java:289)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.response.ServiceResponse.throwIfNecessary(ServiceResponse.java:278)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:165)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.internalCreateItems(ExchangeService.java:594)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.createItem(ExchangeService.java:653)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item.internalCreate(Item.java:247)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item.save(Item.java:363)
    at CopieRdvEasily2Outlook.main(CopieRdvEasily2Outlook.java:385)
```

Comment: Having the full stacktrace might help, e.g. by in identifying what object can't be found. Could it be that the account you're trying to use doesn't exist, the service url has changed or the name of the "calendar" folder is different? Did you try with an Exchange 2016 version value for `exver`?

Comment: Thx for your answer
- exver is used to tell what is the oldest compatible version, exchange 2016 doesn't exist as a value.
- The admin account seems to be able to 'see' the mailboxes still in 2010 but not the ones on 2016 (the admin account got all privileges and is on a 2016 version).

Comment: I updated the message with the full stack

Comment: That error is usually permission related if you using Add-MailboxPermission to give the Admin Account explicit Full Access to the Target mailbox does that help?

Comment: Ok so my problem is solved but unfortunatly I can't tell you how.
A technician added some parameters in outlook to each mailbox but I have no access to this part of our system.
Anyway the issue was not in my code :)